# How to get width of element using React ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a select field, but I can't get width of this select using React Ref.

[image]

`this.selectRef.current` is an object, but it seems there is no way to get width of the element

```
     <Select
        fullWidth
        ref={this.selectRef}
        onChange={event => {
          this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
          });
        }}
        value={this.state.value}
      >
        <MenuItem value={0}>Zero</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={1}>One</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={2}>Two</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={3}>Three</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={4}>Four</MenuItem>
      </Select>
```

Sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/hungry-galileo-eydfw

Comment: Hi fetchenko, please try my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just wrap the `Select` component in a `div` and give that `div` the `ref`.

Additionally, try to use `state` to record the width and define that ref-width reading logic outside of the render. Put it in `componentDidMount()` instead, that way we've ensured that the element has rendered to the screen and we don't need to check if `ref.current` is truthy.

Also you can use`.clientWidth` instead of `.offsetWidth` so that you get the actual element width, not including borders.

[See working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-waterfall-no776):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Select, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";

class MySelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 0,
      open: false,
      width: null
    };

    this.selectRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const width = this.selectRef.current.clientWidth;
    this.setState(
      {
        width: width
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.width)
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.selectRef}>
        <Select
          fullWidth
          ref={this.selectRef}
          onChange={event => {
            this.setState({
              value: event.target.value
            });
          }}
          value={this.state.value}
        >
          <MenuItem value={0}>Zero</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={1}>One</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={2}>Two</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={3}>Three</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={4}>Four</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MySelect;
```